# How do I list out all the dependent classes for a class in a Python module using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, dependencies

Say I have a module named `EmailClient`:

```
class EmailClient(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self._config = config
        self.connect(self._config)

    def connect(self, config):
        # Implement function here
        pass
```

I have another module:

```
class EmailReader(object):

    def __init__(self, client):
        try:
            self._client = client
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def read(self):
        # Implement function here
        pass
```

Now, I write the following driver:

```
from email_client_mod import EmailClient
from email_reader_mod import EmailReader

email_client = EmailClient(config={'something': 'something'})
email_reader = EmailReader(email_client)
```

I will have all the three files: driver.py, email_client_mod.py and email_reader_mod.py

Using Python, I have to write a program so that I can get the information that EmailReader class is dependent on EmailClient. How can I do that?

I read some blog posts but it turned out that we need to have some Dependency Injection but I don't think that is required. Currently, I am able to fetch the inheritance if any using [this](https://github.com/avisrivastava254084/generate_uml/blob/list_classes/get_classes_list.py) code. But I have no idea how am I supposed to get the dependencies?

This question is not a duplicate as finding methods and their usage needs to be extended in theory and in implementation in order to find the dependent classes.

Comment: You'll have to do a full analysis of the AST. This is not an easy task, and you'll have to accept you won't find all references (Python is highly dynamic, and you can write code that'll use `EmailClient` without ever explicitly naming it).

Comment: I've provided a solution before, to the simplified problem of finding uses of imported names. See the duplicate.

Comment: The solution there is not the whole answer, you also have to track `EmailReader()` calls and if a reference to `EmailClient()` is passed in. All this can be solved with more AST analysis but that's really way out of scope for an SO answer.

Comment: Can you guide me for the AST analysis?
What should I look into it?

Comment: See the duplicate; that tracks imports for a single module. The AST is a tree of nodes modelling Python source code; `Import` and `ImportFrom` nodes are created for `import ...` and `from ... import ...` statements. The `ast.NodeVisitor` class I used lots you create hooks to be called for those specific nodes, starting with `visit_...`. Use these to analyze the tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, would it be possible for you to provide an example as an answer or in comments? A simple basic example would get me going. Thank you!

Comment: There is also the [Green Tree Snakes ebook](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which covers AST wrangling in a broader context.

Comment: I picked the duplicate explicitly because it offers an example already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe I am being too dumb. I tried running your code, I could not execute it. No errors, it's just that `used_at` is empty.

In the [simplest example](https://pastebin.com/SdkC79Xw), what would you place in the final code block?

Comment: That example doesn't use any import statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199861/discussion-between-aviral-srivastava-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: @MartijnPieters
I am sorry but neither the duplicate has helped me and nor you marking the question as duplicate. I might be not as good with the terms and conventions of SO but I am sure that a newbie is trying to code something and grab the community's attention and all you have done is to point to a duplicate that doesn't really solve anything!

Comment: The alternative is that this is closed as too broad. I'm sorry, but this is not an easy subject, and giving you a complete working solution would be way too much work. It may well be that AST traversal and processing is too much to ask of you, but there is no 'easier' solution to this problem.